# На сайте footer загружается со 2 раза | Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Проблема следующая. Есть сайт компании по недвижке, при загрузке сайта в первый раз загружается добрая его половина, однако парочка картинок и футер сайта остаются незагруженными, вернее футер загружается, но из-за того, что его бэкграунд не прогрузился то его не видно совсем. Скрины прилагаю. Загружается все до конца примерно через секунд 40-60. Как-будто загрузка приостанавливается с каким-то количеством загруженных материалов и возобновляется после этого.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По скриншотам Вам никто ничем не поможет. Если у Вас сайт загружается 40-60, промониторьте в отладчике какие запросы как долго выполняются и почему.

Comment: При загрузке главной страницы сайта у меня во вкладке Network 300+ реквестов и данных загружается на 154 мегабайта, я не знаю чего Вы ожидали с таким весом главной страницы. Изображения по 1-1,7 мегабайта.

Comment: Как мне тогда оптимизировать изображения без потери качества, вроде я уже это сделал

Comment: А как Вы это делали? Если картинка весит 1,7 мегабайта, то она точно не оптимизирована и обратите внимание на разрешение изображений, зачем там картинки размером 2560х1920 еще и 96 точек на дюйм. Есть сторонние сервисы для этого [imagecompressor](https://imagecompressor.com/ru/) и тп, так же есть плагины, но бесплатный лимит в них маленький. Так же можете затем перегнать изображения в формат webp используя [WebP Express](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express/)